# c# type to handle relative and absolute URI's and local file paths

Tags: c#, path, types, uri

I have a use cases where I will be dealing with both local file paths (e.g. `c:\foo\bar.txt`) and URI's (e.g. `http://somehost.com/fiz/baz`). I also will be dealing with both relative and absolute paths so I need functionality like [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(VS.71).aspx) and friends.

*Is there an existing C# type I should use?* The [Uri type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(VS.71).aspx) might work but at a passing glance, it seems to be URI only.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using the Uri class, it seems to be working.  It turns any file path to the `file:///..." syntax in the Uri. It handles any URI as expected, and it has capacity to deal with relative URIs.  It depends on what else you are trying to do with that path.

(Updated to show the use of relative Uri's):

```
string fileName = @"c:\temp\myfile.bmp";
string relativeFile = @".\woohoo\temp.bmp";
string addressName = @"http://www.google.com/blahblah.html";

Uri uriFile = new Uri(fileName);
Uri uriRelative = new Uri(uriFile, relativeFile);
Uri uriAddress = new Uri(addressName);

Console.WriteLine(uriFile.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(uriRelative.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(uriAddress.ToString());
```

Gives me this output:

```
file:///c:/temp/myfile.bmp  
file:///c:/temp/woohoo/temp.bmp  
http://www.google.com/blahblah.html
```

Comment: that file:/// thing is... inconvenient, but I can live with it if I must. I was really hoping for something more directly set up for it +1

Comment: Well, you can inspect the "LocalPath" property, which will give you the filename in local format (without the file:///).