# How do I create a URI string that correctly points to a .wav file in my Resource directory?

Tags: wpf, media-player

I need to play a sound byte (`MP3` or `wav`) from within a `WPF` application. I would like to use the `MediaPlayer`. I have a `.wav` file with;
 `"Build Action" = Content`  and `"Copy to Output Directory" = "Copy if Newer"` and this file is located in the Resources directory of my app.

However, I just cant get the `URI` string right. (and maybe the Build Action is not correct)

Comment: Can you show us the `URI` string you have currently written?

Comment: This is the one (of many I tried) that isn't working: Uri u = new Uri("file://Resources/SoundByte.wav"); I also have to make sure that I have the Build Action correct

Answer (score 0):

I found this from Tolga Evcimen and it does work:

[how to get relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342123/how-to-get-relative-path-of-a-file-in-visual-studio)

var outPutDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
var SoundBytePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(outPutDirectory, "Resources\SoundByte.wav");