# not using the complete path in deserializing JSON file

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

I deserialize a JSON File in the code below I don't want to use the complete path and if I run this project on any system I won't have any problem.
what should I do?

```
 public static List<DtoCustomer> Deserialize()
            {


            List<DtoCustomer> result =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DtoCustomer>>(
                        File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Customers\Customers\Properties\customer.json"));
                return result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to use the complete path? Relative path instead?

Comment: yes, I want to write the path so it would run on any computer and I do not have to change the path all over again every time.

Comment: And how is the path to the file defined? User input? Or on your program's directory?

Comment: the file is in the program folder. I used properties to get the path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get relative path of a file in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342123/how-to-get-relative-path-of-a-file-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "current directory" of the application instance (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=netframework-4.8)

```
System.IO.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

However, that will get you the "current working directory" and is not necessarily the same as the directory where the program executable resides. If you want *that*, have a look at [Getting the absolute path of the executable, using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658518/getting-the-absolute-path-of-the-executable-using-c)

```
Application.ExecutablePath
```