# how to path the image from Picture Library in c#

Tags: c#, image, path, mediaelement

I want to display picture in my app(MediaElement) from Picture Library using c# and xaml

here my code:

```
media.PosterSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("file//C:/Users/Siio/Pictures/bird.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```

but the image won't appear.

any suggestion?

Update
C#

```
StorageFolder photoFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
List<string> photoTypeFilter = new List<string>();
photoTypeFilter.Add(".png");
QueryOptions queryOption = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, fileTypeFilter);
StorageFileQueryResult queryResults = photoFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> filess = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
foreach (StorageFile fil in filess)
{
     MusicProperties musicProperty = await fil.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
     if (musicProperty.Title == UpdateFav.F_Title)
     {
           Uri uri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Christopher\Pictures\" + UpdateFav.F_Title + ".png");
           Uri uri1 = new Uri(uri.AbsoluteUri);
           BitmapImage im = new BitmapImage(uri1);
           media.PosterSource = im;
     }
}
```

XAML:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="media" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="398" Margin="122,63,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="592" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" PosterSource="Assets/BG2.jpg" MediaOpened="media_MediaOpened"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your absolute file path syntax is incorrect. It is missing a colon after "file". The correct syntax is "file:///". This should have resulted in a [System.UriFormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131565%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The Uri constructor already knows how to handle file paths by appending the "file:///" syntax for you. An easier way to specify file paths is below.

Example:

```
string fileName = @"c:\temp\foo.txt";
Uri uriFile = new Uri(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("Absolute Path: {0}", uri.AbsolutePath);
Console.WriteLine("Absolute Uri: {0}", uri.AbsoluteUri);
```

Output:

> Absolute Path: C:/temp/foo.txt 
>   Absolute Uri: file:///C:/temp/foo.txt

Relevent Question: [c# type to handle relative and absolute URI's and local file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799367/c-sharp-type-to-handle-relative-and-absolute-uris-and-local-file-paths)