# Play lock screen slideshow from local images (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I'm trying to play lock screen slideshow from images stored in local folder. All ways which I found didn't help me. There're four methods in LockScreen class from Windows.System.UserProfile namespace and only one allow you to play slideshow(from images which you want). It's:

```
public static IAsyncOperation<SetImageFeedResult> RequestSetImageFeedAsync(
    Uri syndicationFeedUri
)
```

But 'Uri' parameter must be the external URI of the RSS image feed. That's why I can't use it. Could somebody help me, how o do this?

Comment: Try posting some code, you will get better answers

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use `Uri` for local paths. You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799367/c-sharp-type-to-handle-relative-and-absolute-uris-and-local-file-paths).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, because when i'm trying to use RequestSetImageFeedAsync with local Uri it throw message "Setting the lock-screen slideshow failed. Please try again." That's why I asked question above...

Comment: Maybe it's non-programming problem:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-desktop/issue-with-the-slideshow-on-the-lock-screen/f7e6be5a-a30c-477a-a125-b33685e4a1ba

Comment: Also, I found another interesting answer:
turn on search index and it'll work again. i found it on internet and its really work
Here:
http://www.postseek.com/meta/568f81a90f8a5c517f98cae2274c7b1e

Comment: Yes, I understood, that these ways work, but only if you set slideshow manually from UI. I must set it programmatically.